# CLLocation Change in local update database

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, fmdb, cllocationdistance

I have local database which has the field "distance" which is based on user's current location.
so i have added a logic to update database if there is change in location for every 30sec.

If there is change in the location one time in 30 sec its working fine, but when the device location changes to more to one location within 30 sec, database updated distance is changing.

Can you please let me know whats the mistake i have done here.

Comment: Add some code of **update distance**..?

Comment: And define in what way it's an error, if it just overwrites the distance for each update in the 30 seconds is that an error?

Comment: Cllocation *dblocation; double distance = [dblocation distanceFromLocation:currentLocation]/1000

Comment: in database i have a field called distance, whenever there is change in location database will be updated by calculating the distance of the object in database with current location.                            My problem is: If i change the location to Delhi with in 30sec it works fine, where as if the change location to 1.delhi then again 2. mumbai , database will be updated with the result by merging delhi and mumbai results

Comment: actually its merging the result of previous locations, i,e number of location change it merging the results.